# PyCharm font style bug?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I'm using macOS Mojave 10.14.3 and PyCharm Community 2019.1 .

After I upgraded it to 2019.1, the font of all texts looks dimming, and it gets bright only near the caret. I'm using the font of `Monaco`, and it behaves the same in other fonts too. Other settings are the same as the default.

Maybe it is related to antialiasing, because it does not occurs when I change the settings of antialiasing to `Greyscale` or `No antialiasing` .
But when I select the two options, the text does not get bright even near the caret.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

[image: Example]

Comment: Please try workaround from this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-1348

Comment: Thank you, this is definitely the problem I'm facing... but none of the workarounds there helped me :( Anyway, I'll follow the issue.